# Capturing audio and video from different sources, how to sync?

Tags: ffmpeg, avfoundation

Here is my code:

```
Lapaki:~ Lapaki$ /Users/Lapaki/Desktop/ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 960x540 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate ntsc -thread_queue_size 8B -i "XI:none" -f avfoundation -thread_queue_size 8B -i "none:XI" -vf 'crop=iw-240:ih:120:0' -af 'asetpts=PTS+.58735/TB' -pix_fmt yuv420p -aspect 4:3 -s 720x480 -q:v 3 -maxrate 5000k -bufsize 2000k -acodec ac3 -ac 2 -ab 256k -ar 48000 -f dvd /Users/Lapaki/Desktop/FF\ Test/`date +%F`\ `date +%H_%M_%S`.mpg
ffmpeg version 3.2.3-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=qtkit --disable-indev=x11grab_xcb
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, avfoundation, from 'XI:none':
  Duration: N/A, start: 648413.295900, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 960x540, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Input #1, avfoundation, from 'none:XI':
  Duration: N/A, start: 648413.884042, bitrate: 3072 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_f32le, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 3072 kb/s
Output #0, dvd, to '/Users/Lapaki/Desktop/FF Test/2017-02-16 04_16_33.mpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 5000000/0/200000 buffer size: 2000000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 ac3
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_f32le (native) -> ac3 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7f8e0c8ab400] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
frame=   33 fps=0.0 q=3.0 size=     266kB time=00:00:01.06 bitrate=2051.9kbits/sframe=   49 fps= 48 q=3.0 size=     444kB time=00:00:01.54 bitrate=2358.8kbits/sframe=   64 fps= 42 q=3.0 size=     652kB time=00:00:02.08 bitrate=2560.5kbits/sframe=   79 fps= 39 q=3.0 size=     838kB time=00:00:02.59 bitrate=2642.4kbits/sframe=   94 fps= 37 q=3.0 size=    1022kB time=00:00:03.07 bitrate=2720.0kbits/sframe=  109 fps= 36 q=3.0 size=    1208kB time=00:00:03.59 bitrate=2756.5kbits/sframe=  124 fps= 35 q=3.0 size=    1406kB time=00:00:04.07 bitrate=2830.0kbits/sframe=  127 fps= 35 q=3.0 Lsize=    1474kB time=00:00:04.19 bitrate=2876.4kbits/s dup=12 drop=0 speed=1.15x    
video:1310kB audio:113kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.604597%
```

The start of `Input #0` is 648413.295900, and the start of `Input #1` is 648413.884042.

I've been able to keep the audio and video in very close sync by subtracting the two values (which I assume are wallclock values), and using the [asetpts audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) to delay the audio stream of the recorded mpeg-2 file by that amount.

I'd like to be able to do this exactly though, and that value changes slightly every time I start a new capture. Not to mention, I'd like to be able to do this reliably on different machines, where I assume the value will most likely be different, thus using a calculation as opposed to a fixed number is obviously the best option, if it's possible.

Is there a way to subtract the wallclock start time of input #0 from the wallclock start time of input #1? I'd like to do this inside the asetpts filter, instead of manually finding the difference from a previous run, which again is slightly different every time...

I was thinking something like `-af asetpts=PTS-([1:0]RTCSTART-[0:0]RTCSTART)/TB` might work, but I have no idea how to format it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The asetpts filter can only reference the attributes of the stream it's processing. Have you tried using just a single AVfoundation to feed both A and V?

Comment: @Mulvya, I tried that first using `-i "XI:XI"`, but the A/V is still out of sync. Does `aresample=async=1` do something similar to what I'm trying to do with `asetpts`?

Comment: What the aresample does is to pad the audio with silence if the input feed stops transmitting intermittently. Else, ffmpeg will "pull forward" the next received audio frame to be contiguous with the last one.  It won't correct initial async without an express offset value, though. Ok, what you can try now is to add `-copyts` before `-i XI:XI` and output to .ts instead of .mpg

Comment: @Mulvya, from [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video): "Using a complex filtergraph, you can speed up video and audio at the same time:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv`". So I was thinking a complex filtergraph seemed at least somewhat promising to using finding the difference between the `RTCSTART` of video and audio streams. Definitely not possible?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter if it's a simple filterchain or filtergraph. the setpts filters can only refer to the single input fed to them.

Comment: That's too bad, @Mulvya. Is there a way to calculate the difference between the RCSTART of the audio and video stream some other way? And then use that difference as an offset somehow?